# Node.js: Regular Expression to read email from string

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I take an e-mail address from `"XXX <email@email.com>"` ? I don't want to get the "< >".

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a better example of the kind of input you're working with, and what you mean by "the < >"?

Comment: The input is within the string. Is when you get an email as: "First Last <email@gmail.com>". I want to know which email is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really simply (no need for regex!)

```
var components = emailAddress.split('<')

if(components.length > 1)
{
    var emailAddress = components[1].replace('>', '');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one based on Tejs' answer. Simple to understand and I think a bit more elegant

```
// Split on < or >
var parts = "XXX <email@email.com>".split(/[<>]/);
var name = parts[0], email = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getEmailsFromString(input) {
    var ret = [];
    var email = /\"([^\"]+)\"\s+\<([^\>]+)\>/g;    
    var match;

    while ( match = email.exec(input) ) {
        ret.push({'name': match[1], 'email': match[2]});
    }    

    return ret;
}

var str = '"Name one" <foo@domain.com>, ..., "And so on" <andsoon@gmx.net>';
var emails = getEmailsFromString(str);
```

credit: [How to find out emails and names out of a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364779/how-to-find-out-emails-and-names-out-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work for your example.

```
/<([^>]+)/
```

It searches for anything after the '<' that is not a '>' and that is returned in your matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(aero|coop|info|museum|name))$
```

Matches e-mail addresses, including some of the newer top-level-domain extensions, such as info, museum, name, etc. Also allows for emails tied directly to IP addresses.

Comment: This may even work, but it looks like Greek to me. Answers should always have some kind of explanation.

Comment: This is doing much more than was asked, I think it confuses more than helps. This is for email validation, not to strip an email out of the string provided by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive if I'm understanding you correctly.  If you want to get the email domain ie gmail.com or hotmail.com then you could just use

```
var x =string.indexOf("@");  var y =string.subString(x)
```

this will give you the string y as the email domain.

Answer (score 0):

To just grab what's inside the angle brackets, you can use the following:

```
var pattern = /<(.*)>/;
pattern.exec("XXX <foo@bar.com>"); // this returns ["<foo@bar.com>", "foo@bar.com"]
```