# Extract special text type with imacros

Tags: javascript, extract, imacros

i would like to get an EVAL code for extract email address from text, 
searching stackoverflow i found this code

```
var re = /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/g;
```

[Extract all email addresses from bulk text using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440444/extract-all-email-addresses-from-bulk-text-using-jquery)
i would likw to know how to create an EVAL code from this function
i tried  this but failed,

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var re = /(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/g;")
```

so please help in writing this code.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET testString "bla bla bla xyz@mail.com bla bla bla"
SET email EVAL("'{{testString}}'.match(/(([^<>()[\\]\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\]\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+)*)|(\\\".+\\\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/g)[0];")
PROMPT {{email}}
```