# Parsing string to find email within string via Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm not a new coder, but new to google app scripts. I am trying to take a string and find the email address contained within the string.

string = "This is the body of the cell where I will be looking. This body has an email in it somewhere like john.doe@aol.com here.";

email = FindEmail(string);

MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Completion Email", "", "this is the email message");

I need to build a function called FindEmail but frankly have no idea how to start.

Comment: Find the position of the '@' and then find the nearest preceding and following space? Whatever is in between that range is most likely you're email address.

Comment: i don't know the code to do that.

Comment: Although you're using Google Apps Script, the operation you're doing is entirely Javascript, so this question is a duplicate of [How to find out emails and names out of a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364779/how-to-find-out-emails-and-names-out-of-a-string-in-javascript).

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312662/regex-for-email-matching) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140955/use-javascript-to-find-email-address-in-a-string)... and probably others!

Answer (score 4):

While there are numerous solutions to this on SO already, the ones I've found need tweaking to provide the simplicity you're looking for.

- [How to find out emails and names out of a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364779/how-to-find-out-emails-and-names-out-of-a-string-in-javascript)
- [Regex for email matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312662/regex-for-email-matching)
- [Use javascript to find email address in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140955/use-javascript-to-find-email-address-in-a-string)
- [Get all email addresses in a string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779465/get-all-email-addresses-in-a-string-with-javascript)
- [Many more...](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20find%20email%20address)

Here's a simple function condensed from all those other answers - the regular expression is a bit of overkill, actually, but can also be used to validate in many cases. It returns an *array* of addresses, so if you only want the first one, you would code `email = findEmails(string)[0]`... but really, you should do some error checking before trusting that.

```
/**
 * Return an array of all email addresses found in input string.
 */
function FindEmails(input) {
  var regex = /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/gm
  var result = input.match(regex);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An email address parsing library "email-addresses" has been adapted for Google Apps Script. Source is [forked and available as a gist](https://github.com/mogsdad/email-addresses).

- Publicly available, library key M26NvEFUvGLQadhq7G3OQmgFzUAA6_aCl.
- Documentation [available here](https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/M26NvEFUvGLQadhq7G3OQmgFzUAA6_aCl/1).

However... it will not find the email address in the string example you give! It expects the string containing addresses to loosely conform to RFC 5322.